# affecting parent element on clicking child element

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function qaw(elem) {
  mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");
  for (i = 0; i < mydiv.length; i++) {
    mydiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
  button = document.querySelector(".btn");
  for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      mydiv[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mydiv" onclick="qaw(this)" id="">
  <div class="btn"><a href="javascript:void">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that background of all mydiv class elements turn to blue when it is clicked on any btn class element. there is anyway to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Change last bit to this:

```
button = document.querySelector(".btn");
for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(j=0;j<mydiv.length;j++){
        mydiv[j].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
});
```

This makes it so that when any button is hit, all divs are set to blue using a for loop, rather than just the particular one with the button.

Comment: not getting blue background after applying your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which changes all divs into blue :

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".myDivs");

function changeAll() {
    [].forEach.call(divs, function(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });
}
```

Assign this function to every *button* click event.

**Complete** :

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
var myDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".myDiv");

function changeAll() {
  [].forEach.call(myDivs, function(div) {
    div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  });
}

[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", changeAll);
});
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```